# How to "part" modulo division.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to know the remainder from modulo division of 30 digit number (it's always 30 digit) by 97 (it's always 97). I'm using for this purpose online spreadsheet built-in functions. But unfortunately error occurs when the following is true: (divisor * 1125900000000) is less than or equal to dividend. So, I have to find a way, to bypass this limitation using only basic math functions, and keep solution as easy as possible.

For explanation, let's use an example:
MOD(dividend, divisor)
MOD(160014621892776920000001252142, 97)

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note that $100 \equiv 3\pmod{97}$, $10000\equiv 9\pmod{97}$, etc.

Comment: It's not clear what limitation you face, but if you need to decrease the dividend you can split it into two $15$ digit chunks $A,B := A\cdot \color{#c00}{10^{15}}+B\equiv A\cdot \color{#c00}{45}+B\pmod{\!97}.\ \ $

Answer (score -2):

Surprised that this question was downvoted, as it is a legitimate math problem.  Further, it is very plausible that the OP (i.e. original poster) lacks the math training, and therefore can't really show work.  Beyond that, the posted question does provide context.  Using John Omielan's comment as a guide, I will walk through the sample problem.

> MOD(160014621892776920000001252142, 97)

First, re-express the dividend as $~A + B + C + D + E + F,~$ where

$$A = \left(16001 \times 10^{25}\right) \\
B = \left(46218 \times 10^{20}\right) \\
C = \left(92776 \times 10^{15}\right) \\
D = \left(92000 \times 10^{10}\right) \\
E = \left(00012 \times 10^{5}\right) \\
F = \left(52142 \times 10^{0}\right). \\
$$

Next, consider that

$$10^5 \equiv 90 \pmod{97} \implies \\
10^{10} \equiv 90^2 \equiv 49 \pmod{97} \implies \\
10^{15} \equiv 49 \times 90 \equiv 45 \pmod{97} \implies \\
10^{20} \equiv 45 \times 90 \equiv 73 \pmod{97} \implies \\
10^{25} \equiv 73 \times 90 \equiv 71 \pmod{97}.$$

The next step is to compute the $~\pmod{97}~$ congruency classes of each of the 6 variables:

$$A \equiv (71 \times 16001) \equiv 7 \pmod{97}. \\
B \equiv (73 \times 46218) \equiv 60 \pmod{97}. \\
C \equiv (45 \times 92776) \equiv 40 \pmod{97}. \\
D \equiv (49 \times 92000) \equiv 22 \pmod{97}. \\
E \equiv (90 \times 00012) \equiv 13 \pmod{97}. \\
F \equiv (1 \times 52142) \equiv 53 \pmod{97}.$$

Therefore,

$$A + B + C + D + E \equiv 7 + 60 + 40 + 22 + 13 + 53 \\
\equiv 1 \pmod{97}.$$

**Note**
Answer sanity checked via small Java program, using the BigInteger class.  Other programming languages (i.e. C, Python, ...) should have similar facilities.